# Характеристика во множественном числе

Tags: грамматика, множественное-число

Уважаемые, задаюсь странный вопросом. Для определения характеристики чего-либо во множественном числе, мы характеристику ставим в единственном или во множественном числе?

В единственном числе понятно:

- девушка с **круглым лицом**.

А вот во множественном как правильно?

- девушки с **круглым лицом**? или девушки с **круглыми лицами**?

Первое звучит так, будто у всех **одно круглое лицо**, тогда как второе звучит так, будто у всех по **несколько круглых лиц**.

Это может Вам показаться странным, но очень меня беспокоит.

То же самое с другим примером.

- Шар **красного цвета**.

А во множественном?

- Шары **красного цвета**? или Шары **красных цветов**?

Answer (score 3):

1) **Девушки с круглыми лицами**

Выбор числа определяется предлогом С, поэтому девушки и лица считаются отдельно.

Чижовы все были рыжие, с круглыми лицами и конопушками.

Никто не поверит, что толстые неповоротливые люди с большими животами и розовыми отвислыми щеками пишут любовные письма ...или мрачно ходят по два часа около какого-нибудь магазина, уныло дожидаясь знакомого стука высоких каблучков.

2) **Шары красного цвета (один оттенок),** признак обозначен Р.п., поэтому используется ед. число. **Шары красных цветов** ― это обозначение разных оттенков красного цвета, в реальных ситуациях обычно не употребляется.

Comment: А как быть с: Мужчины, не носившие шляпы или Мужчины, не носившие шляп. Девушки, у которых короткие стрижки или Девушки, у которых короткая стрижка.

Comment: Шляпы и мужчины также считаются отдельно. Короткие стрижки могут быть разными (мн. число) или это общий признак (ед. число). Поэтому каждую  ситуацию приходится рассматривать  творчески и индивидуально, вряд ли вы найдете общее решение. Но обычно все это делается на уровне интуиции.

Comment: не совсем понял. Я хоть и русский, но как-то для меня более правильными кажутся варианты: Мужчины, не носившие шляп и Девушки, у которых короткая стрижка.

Comment: Они и есть более правильные. Девушки, у которых короткая стрижка (обобщенный признак)

Comment: Предлог "с" не всегда решает в эту сторону, напр. вряд ли можно говорить о наборе "девушек с хорошими внешностями".

Comment: Сущ. "внешность" имеет форму мн. числа согласно словарю, но не могу понять, в каком случае эта форма употребляется.